# Does the Dropbox core API supports Order by?

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to list the Dropbox files with datetime descending order in C# but I couldn't find any way.I read the document https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs

Does the Dropbox core API supports Order by?

Thanks in advance

Comment: no it doesn't support

Comment: Thanks. @ Pranav Patel